# How do I conditionally get code to loop back to specific point in code in java?

Tags: java, sqlite, loops

I am creating an application that automatically sorts and organizes files into a database​. I have written my code to read files within the imported folder one at a time, and process them into the DB. However, I am having trouble looping this process, so that I can process files that are nested in any amount of folders within the original folder that the user wants to input.

I simply need to instruct my program to go back to a specific part of my code and start running from there again.

Another possible way to solve this issue would be to create a way to list out all of the individual files within folder (including all the files within subfolders), and I could easily fit that into my program too.

I tried using labeled continue, return, and break keywords based off of an answer I got online, but I never expected those to succeed in looping my code back to a specific spot.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setSelectedFiles(null);
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

//Getting file paths from within folder
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String file = f.getAbsolutePath();

if (f.isDirectory()) {
//Need to loop back to here
File folder = new File(file);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
//Code here is run if there is a folder within a folder. I tested it too
//I want the code here to loop back above where it says "Need to loop back to here"
}

if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) { //Once I list the files from within the folder, their information gets assigned variable here, and the rest of my program sorts it and saves it to DB accordingly.                           

//Everything below here is not important, but it might be helpful to see what happens each file with the folders.                   
System.out.println(listOfFiles[i]);

String filename = (listOfFiles[i].getName()); //For Files
Long filemodified = (listOfFiles[i].lastModified());
String filepath = (listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
Long filesizeraw = (listOfFiles[i].length());
long filehashcode = (listOfFiles[i].hashCode());
String fileparent = (listOfFiles[i].getParent());
```

Currently, there is no error message. It would process any individual files directly in the imported file (not nested in any folder within the folder), but wouldn't get to any of the files that are in folders within folders.

Comment: You are already using for loops.  What about *while loops* and all other controls structures available in java?  Stack overflow is not a good place to answer full tutorials on basic programming methods.

Comment: One of the solutions is to refactor your code and use recursion

Comment: @CPerkins I know how to use while loops and I don't think it fits what I am trying to do. You may have misread my question, do you mind taking another look at it?

Comment: @JohnPeabody  GirishB's suggestion of recursion is a good solution.  Recursion can take the form a single function or it can be implemented using objects and methods.  But formal study of recursion shows that many (most?) recursive algorithms can be unwrapped into basic loops.  If while loops (and for, if, etc.), functions, and objects could not solve the problem, then searching for some new hidden aspect of the language may turn out disappointing.  Your challenge is legitimate, it's just that there are so many ways to do it, that it is likely too broad for a SO question.

Comment: If you don't want to do recursion (which is probably the way to go), I think what @CPerkins is getting at with while is this. Throw your main directory into a list of unexplored directories. Then while(the list of unexplored directories is not empty){take the first off the list. Go through all its files, doing whatever you need with the actual files and stuffing all directories encountered onto your list of unexplored directories}

Comment: After reviewing the newer "How to ask" and other help pages, I decided maybe I was being too restrictive and so started drafting an answer... but exactly as I feared, I found myself starting to explain variable scope, data encapsulation, the basic of defining functions and when separate functions are most useful... all in an effort to properly explain recursion.  It starts to become an entire primer on programming.  This is not to be rude, only to point out that the title question really is so fundamental that there is no short answer other than "try recursion" or "try a while loop".

Comment: @CPerkins thank you both for the answers. Recursion is definitely the right way to go here. I have decent experience with it, and I am using it now. Just a pain to re-write a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Another possible way to solve this issue would be to create a way to list out all of the individual files within folder (including all the files within subfolders), and I could easily fit that into my program too**

Although this doesn't do the SQLite inserts, the following class extracts a list (of File objects) the files (thus file name and path are available via the File object).

```
public class FTS {

    private ArrayList<File> mFileList; //Resultant list of Files extracted
    private String mBaseDirectory; // The Directory to search
    private long mSubDirectoryCount; // The count of the subdirectories

    //Constructor
    public FTS(String directory) {
        this.mBaseDirectory = directory;
        this.mSubDirectoryCount = 0;
        buildFileListing(this.mBaseDirectory);
    }

    //
    private void buildFileListing(String directory) {
        // Initialise the ArrayList for the result
        if (mFileList == null) {
            mFileList = new ArrayList(){};
        }
        //Get the File (directory to process)
        File dir = new File(directory);
        // Get the List of the Directories contents
        String[] filelist = dir.list();
        // If empty (null) then return
        if (filelist == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Loop through the directory list
        for (String s: filelist) {
            //get the current list item as a file
            File f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + s);
             // is it a file or directory?
            if (f.isFile() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
                this.mFileList.add(f);  // If a file then add the file to the extracted list
            } else {
                // If a directory then increment the count of the subdirectories processed
                mSubDirectoryCount++;
                // and then recursively call this method to process the directory
                buildFileListing(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    // return the list of extracted files
    public ArrayList<File> getFileList() {
        return this.mFileList;
    }

    // return the number of sub-directories processed
    public long getSubDirectoryCount() {
        return this.mSubDirectoryCount;
    }
}
```

An example usage of the above is :-

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       FTS fileTreeSearch;
       String BaseDirectory = "E:" + File.separator;
       List<File> files = (fileTreeSearch = new FTS(BaseDirectory)).getFileList();
       System.out.println("Extracted " + String.valueOf(files.size()) + " files, from " + String.valueOf(fileTreeSearch.getSubDirectoryCount()) + " sub-directories of " + BaseDirectory);
       /* this commented out code would process all the extracted files
       for (File f: files) {
           System.out.println("File is " + f.getName() + "\t\t path " + f.getAbsolutePath());
       } 
       */
    }
}
```

Example output from running the above :-

> ```
> Extracted 186893 files, from 54006 sub-directories of E:\
> ```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Your code is clear, easy to read, and effective.